# Deedle series.ValuesAll raise Error: OptionalValue.Value: Value is not available

Tags: f#, deedle

The ValuesAll function of the Deedle series according to the doco is to

```
Returns a collection of values, including possibly missing values. Note that the length of this sequence matches the `Keys` sequence.
```

However the following code will raise an error OptionalValue.Value: is not available. Is this expected behaviour? I was expecting ValuesAll can return double.nan

```
#I "..\..\packages\Deedle.1.2.4"
#load "Deedle.fsx"
open System
open System.Globalization
open System.Collections.Generic
open Deedle

let ts = [DateTime.Now.Date => Double.NaN; DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1.0) => 1.0] |> series
ts.Print()
ts.ValuesAll
> 
27/01/16 12:00:00 AM -> <missing> 
28/01/16 12:00:00 AM -> 1         


val ts : Series<DateTime,float> =

27/01/16 12:00:00 AM -> <missing> 
28/01/16 12:00:00 AM -> 1         

val it : seq<float>

> ts.ValuesAll
;;
val it : seq<float> = Error: OptionalValue.Value: Value is not available
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different implementations for `valuesAll` [here](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/fc8453e578d52c560f55f9eb783e91576453b38c/src/Deedle/SeriesModule.fs#L411) and C#-friendly `ValuesAll` [here](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/fc8453e578d52c560f55f9eb783e91576453b38c/src/Deedle/Series.fs#L109). The latter one just accesses the `.Value` property of optional value and its signature is `seq<float>`, not `seq<float opt>`. Either implementation or docs are not consistent here.

When I used Deedle I filtered series with `|> Series.dropMissing` as a quick workaround when I needed only present values.